# Automatic rename from a list (DOS)

Tags: dos, rename

I was wondering if it was possible to rename a file by a list. I explain my case :

I work in a japanese company  and I receive on my pc some files with a japanese name, and i would like rename these automaticly, like this example : ファイルの.ジュニチ.pdf -> File.Junichi.pdf, because most of these files i receive get the same name, every week. I've search but most of posts was about renaming a lot of files with the same name.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably write a .bat file to accomplish this using for-in-do:

```
FOR %%a IN (*.pdf) DO rename %%a newfile%counter%.pdf
```

...or something like that (obviously you'll want to increment %counter%).  If you can though, you'll have an easier time writing a Powershell script to accomplish this.  I wrote one that does something similar to this a while ago (renameWebFiles.ps1):

```
$location = $args[0];

$Files = get-childitem $location;

foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    $newFileName = "webonly_" + $File.name
    $inFile = $location + "\" + $File.name
    rename-item $inFile $newFileName
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The problem is when i do my batch with "FOR %%ファイルの IN (*.pdf) DO rename %%ファイルの newfile%counter%.pdf " (Without quotes), that's doesnt work with kanji, but with normal letter that's work perfectly, do you know why ? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done much (anything) with kanji in DOS.  Although, I do remember reading somewhere that DOS has issues with kanji-based filenames, though.  Maybe you should give the Powershell approach a try, and see if that yields any success.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Just that's strange because when i write %%abc, only the first letter is used, not bc, you know why? Thanks